# Adding a slash after hostname and before query params

Tags: javascript

I need to add a slash in case there is no path in url before "?" query params.

For instance
**https://www.example.com?foo=bar** turns out to be **https://www.example.com/?foo=bar**

This change i only need to do once in a url:

**https://www.example.com?foo=bar&url=https://www.example.com?aa=b**
will be **https://www.example.com/?foo=bar&url=https://www.example.com?aa=b**

Also, In case there is path,  no don't need to add this slash
**https://www.example.com/path?foo=bar** will remain **https://www.example.com/path?foo=bar**

Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: A simple `.replace('.com?', '.com/?')` should suffice. Also the value of your `url` parameter should be encoded.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface when creating URLs and it will get them right for you, especially if you use the attached `searchParams` ([URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)) for manipulating query parameters.

```js
const base = "https://example.com";

const url1 = new URL(base);
url1.searchParams.append("foo", "bar");
console.log(url1.toString());
  // ➡ https://example.com/?foo=bar

// Query parameters will be encoded correctly
url1.searchParams.append("url", "https://www.example.com?aa=b");
console.log(url1.toString());
  // ➡ https://example.com/?foo=bar&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%3Faa%3Db

const url2 = new URL("/path", base);
url2.searchParams.append("foo", "bar");
console.log(url2.toString());
  // ➡ https://example.com/path?foo=bar
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
url = 'https://www.example.com?foo=bar&url=https://www.example.com?aa=b'
url = url.match(/com\/\?/) ? url : url.replace('com?', 'com/?')
console.log(url)

url = 'https://www.example.com/?foo=bar&url=https://www.example.com?aa=b'
url = url.match(/com\/\?/) ? url : url.replace('com?', 'com/?')
console.log(url)
```

Comment: What about `'https://www.example.com/?foo=bar&url=https://www.example.com?aa=b'`?

Comment: That's a good point, I've modified things to check for cases that don't need to be changed.